# Keras: Struggle with loss-functions w/ additional parameters and merging them

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, loss-function

I'm quite new to the field of data-science and fiddle around with some **time-series-data**, in my case stock-data. I want to learn a **neural-net to forecast** them, as everyone has tried to do some time I guess? :D
I'm using **tensorflow/keras** and **python** for this.

I'm not really convinced to ever get something to work, but I want to try. Doing this, I'm stuck with my loss-function. It's mainly about *"is this even **right**"* on the one hand and it's a question on *"**how** to get it work"* on the other.

#### Context

In my case, I have the last n bars (open, min, max, close for each) as an input, for this illustration say it's: `[[1,1,2,2], [2,2,3,3]]`

The output should be a suitable "stop-loss" and "limit", so mathematically I want the system to generate the value that probably stays a bit under the interval the next bars are in (in case of "stop-loss") and the value that stays in this interval but is as high as possible (in case of "limit").

Let's say this output has a format like `[3,4]`

#### Now regarding the loss-function I got problems with.

Defining a custom loss-function takes the output-format twice, one is the predicted value ("y_pred") and one is the expected value ("y_real"). This is OK for algorithms that calculate the distance from one to another in a let's say "classical" way.

My idea (ok, guess many had this before...) is to use the real profit/loss (in financial terms) to implement the loss (in terms of training neural nets).

This implies different things and introduces my **questions**:

- I need to get **additional complex data** (i.e. the future bars to detect whether my stop or loss is triggered first) in my loss-function. Technically I know how to do that, but is this the **right direction**?
- The additional data has a different format than y_pred. It's both lists and they got the same size, but the one contains more complex input-like data of the future bars and the other contains output-like data, for both see code-snipplets above or example below). Can you tell me how to merge them? I could do that with lists, but since I got tensors I have no idea **how to iterate over and merge them** one-by-one. Mapping seems interesting, but then I get many more pairs than I need. See example (*) below.
- The loss function will only be **differentiable in parts**, because I need to have some "switches" since one point up or down can make a huge difference (if my limit is exactly the maximum, then my profit is maximized, but if it's only a bit higher, then it's not reached and I have got huge losses. Will the loss-function do what I want? Is it some kind of obvious for you experts that it e.g. **won't ever convergate** or will be stuck in some silly valley?

#### Example

(*) Here is my example for illustration:

**Input**

```
[
  [
    [1,1,1,1],
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3]
  ],
  [
    [2,2,2,2],
    [3,3,3,3],
    [4,4,4,4]
  ],...
]
```

**Expected output**

```
[
  [3,5],
  [4,6],...
]
```

**Additional data for loss-function (future of input-bars)**

```
[
  [
    [4,4,4,4],
    [5,5,5,5]
  ],
  [
    [5,5,5,5],
    [6,6,6,6]
  ],...
]
```

**The format I want to get**

```
[
  [
    [
      [4,4,4,4],
      [5,5,5,5]
    ],
    [3,5]
  ],
  [
    [
      [5,5,5,5],
      [6,6,6,6]
    ],
    [4,6]
  ]
]
```

Hope you understand my issue and would appreciate if you took the time to give some feedback on it.

Best wishes,
Dennis

Comment: Hi Dennis, did you solve this problem? 
I have the same your problem

Comment: Hi Aso Strife, this topic was blocked so hard I lost motivation on it.
I got the values in there by using functions that return functions, that kinda worked.
But since the whole project didn't ever convergate but broke up in all the runs, I sadly cannot verify whether this solution is correct or not.
But in short, no, I haven't got an answer to the question whether this way leads to where I wanted to get.